# protect wordpress uploaded files access from non-logged-in users?

Tags: privacy, wordpress, file-upload, file-access

I have launched a WordPress site for a private group of people. This site serves as a public representational site, but also they make "posts" with "Private" checked, so only logged in users can see those posts. Everything would be OK, but they also upload image/document files and attach/include them to private or public posts. All is OK with public posts, but when the file is used in a private post, we assume the file is confidential. But here WordPress allows accessing any uploaded file directly via a link (URL), even if you're not logged in to the site from the browser.

I tried searching but can't find something that would actually work. Even FB private groups have this file access restriction for outsiders, GitLab also has permissions, where if you are not in a project, you can't access ANYTHING that's there. It seems like if I used WordPress/Joomla/Drupal, it would be hacking/messing around to achieve what I want.

Do you have any suggestions, maybe to access uploaded files through WordPress (PHP) and not directly via web server, so via PHP I could make some SQL queries and check in what posts that file is included and whether the user is logged in? Also maybe there are some plugins that do exactly that?

P.S. I wouldn't be asking if I knew WordPress in-and-out, but in this case, I just launched it more or less.

Comment: You probably need to ask on wordpress.SE. All I can tell you is that there are plugins that do what you want, but they are generally not free and probably extremely bloated (they might also implement lots of advanced stuff you don't need). Otherwise you need to develop your own plugin, and the easiest way might be to use htaccess to internally rewrite every image or document to index.php, and then use some WP hooks to check all the parameters you need before serving the file.

Answer (score 1):

One option to fix this problem is to store the file contents in the database as a blob. This could be problematic if the files are large, however, as you predicted: you can ensure that the recipient is authorised before delivering the content. Another option might be to move the file when the post is saved so that it can't be accessed directly at the http endpoint.

In either of these cases, you might then use `.htaccess` to redirect any `GET` requests for files within that directory to a new php file that delivers the content. You can check to see if the user is logged in before delivery using standard WordPress function, and/ or pull the content out of the database on the fly. These options require custom code to achieve.

(Is the file being checked for malign content, and the filename being changed to something non-deterministic, by the way? This is a vector for attack.)

If you don't wish to code, you might consider a parallel installation of *[ownCloud](https://owncloud.com/download-server/)* or *[NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/install/#instructions-server)* and then in the private post, your users place a link to the file within the other service. Both of these applications provide a number of different clients for various devices, as well as the ability to restrict access to specific groups and users.

Comment: "To move the file when post is saved": as much as I understand, action of uploading file (even while writing a post) and submitting a post are two different actions. Also I wonder, does this involve editing WP's PHP files code, or creating some minimal plugin?

Comment: I also thought about hosting NextCloud or similar service. But then can WP+NC both use same users DB w/o problems? I would expect that such cloud service would even have built-in PDF viewer.

Comment: WP and NC databases are discrete, however, you would be able to automatically create NC cred's at the time of user creation in WP - see: *[wp_pre_insert_user_data](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_pre_insert_user_data/)*, but see my next comment for add'l considerations

Comment: if you're going to automatically create an account on another system you must consider that this functionality may be exploited - having given it little thought, I would probably hash the user's WP password immediately using the *[NC hashing function](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/blob/master/lib/private/Security/Hasher.php)*, then place this in a persistent queue 'somewhere' - I would also give serious consideration to the queue being vetted by an admin before accounts are created in NC

Comment: ps. yes, both NC and WP can peacefully co-exist on the same host, as their respective database configuration prefixes and separate accounts ensure they don't interfere - it would likely be easier to achieve what you wish if they're both within the same context, however, if they're separate there's not much prob. once you add new files to NC you'd then trigger a scan and re-sync of the file-system vs file-cache DB, viz. *https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html?#scan*

Comment: there's nothing stopping you editing WP files, however, you should probably use a plugin when the possibility exists - you can also just add a new file to the WP directory and then include and call WP functions to check if the user is logged in (`is_user_logged_in`), etc. - accessing this file would occur via redirect in `.htaccess`  (this has nothing to do with NC)